# Is my plan for providing temporary power to a home construction site reasonable?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, meter

We're beginning construction on some new property that will have a detached garage (2024) and a house (2025).  We were planning on 200A service, but after talking to people decided to go with 400A.

We’ll start with a temporary power pole for construction that will have the meter main with two 200A disconnects and 200A panel that we can use for construction and the well.  We’ll either leave this power pole as a permanent power pole or possibly move it to the back of the garage once the garage is built.

I’m looking at an Eaton meter main that gives two 200A disconnects.

I think we would just do a fairly inexpensive outdoor panel to use for construction and the well that would be pretty simple to connect up to the meter main on our power pole.

When we’re ready to hook up the garage, I think we can either do it from the feed-through lugs on the 200A panel or move the Meter Main to the garage and rewire the well from the panel in the garage.

We could just leave the 200A service for the house alone until we’re ready to hook that up in 2025.

Any thoughts or concerns with this? Does this seem like a good option for this?

Comment: *"talking with people"* I hope those people didn't recommend tankless electric water heating. Unless you have tankless electric water heating, a really huge house, a big workshop or way overdone EV charging, you probably don't need more than 200A.

Comment: Agree with @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that unless you have a really unusual setup, 400A is probably way more than you actually will be needing.  There are lots of ways to be smart about the amount of power your property actually needs, rather than just adding up all of the possible needs and assuming they'll all be on at the same time.   If you decide you really need that 400A service, you'll need to talk with your service provider first, to make sure they can actually provide that much power to your location, and are also willing to provide that much power.

Comment: How much square footage of house + garage are you planning to put on this property, and do you have other major loads (such as a workshop) that you are planning for?

Comment: Plus also consider energy efficiency, particularly for HVAC. Planned right, *which you can do much more easily for a new house than an existing one*, your HVAC power load may be much lower than you might expect.

Comment: Thanks @manessahkatz and @Milwrdfan! I hear you and I DO appreciate those thoughts on needed amps. No on the electric tankless water heater or huge house. (2000sqft) We do plan on radiant floors, a large garage with an ADU, and want to be prepared for whatever EV charging options there are in the future. We still don't expect to be close to 200a, but "those people" are saying it's a little bit extra $ now (about $3-4k) that will keep all our options open in the future.  I just asked our electric company for a 400a bid today, so we'll see what they say.

Comment: I wish $3k was a "little bit" for me. You're going to find that all those little bits add up to a "big lump of cash" across your entire project. Don't overkill without a good reason. Are you also going to install a fourth garage stall in case you someday buy a snowmobile? Note that the symbol for Amps or amperage is `A`, not `a`.

Comment: Going from 200A to 400A service later (assuming 400A is available) isn't a major deal if everything else is in place for it.  You can still feed two 200A subpanels from a 200A meter/main panel. It has the advantages of not paying for 400A service if you only need < 200A.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I definitely hear you.  Yes, $3k is a lot. I struggled with just the extra $500 for 3" conduit over 2". I just figured it's a small % (<1%) of the total house cost. @FreeMan - are you saying I can connect a 400A service though a 200A meter/main?

Comment: I don't believe so - the meter/main would need to be able to handle the full power being supplied. The suggestion is that you start with a 200A service, but set everything up to upgrade to 400A if/when you ever need to. That way all the cost is up front, but you're not paying for a 400A service if you're only using 150A for the next 10 years before all these new demands are installed. The upgrade to 400A at that point would be reasonably painless.

Comment: @MikeS -- can you define "large garage" please?

Comment: Can I get a 400A service now with a 400A meter, but only hook it up to a single 200A (ranch) panel to start with that will be used for construction and the well and then once our garage is done go to a subpanel from that 200A (ranch) panel, and then later once our house is done, wire up the 200A panel in the house from the 400A meter? So the 400A meter would only be connected to that single 200A (ranch) panel initially.